# How do i rotate a picturebox according to my mouse

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I would want to rotate my picturebox which contains an image. The image will just spin around following the mouse, but the position of the image is fixed. Any idea on how it should be done? Btw using Visual Studio 2012 C# Windows phone application for Windows Phone 8. I've did a little research on google but the other codes were from VS2012 using a WinForm But it's different now I'm not able to use their code. So I was hoping I could find some answer at here!

Currently now I have this

```
    private void arrowHead_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        Duration Time_duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5));
        Storyboard MyStory = new Storyboard();
        MyStory.Duration = Time_duration;
        DoubleAnimation My_Double = new DoubleAnimation();
        My_Double.Duration = Time_duration;
        MyStory.Children.Add(My_Double);
        RotateTransform MyTransform = new RotateTransform();
        Storyboard.SetTarget(My_Double, MyTransform);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(My_Double, new PropertyPath("Angle"));
        My_Double.To = 15;
        arrowHead.RenderTransform = MyTransform;
        arrowHead.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);

        //stackPanel1.Children.Add(image1);

        MyStory.Begin();
    }
```

This is a [print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmhGj.jpg) of my work. I want to make the red arrowhead to move according to my mouse.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to obtain the angle that the mouse is offset from some reference point.  Here's how I would do it.  I'm not a C# developer, so I can't give code for this, but I can explain the principles involved:

- Get the location of the mouse as a point, and subtract the point that's the center of your image.  For example, if the mouse is at `(100, 80)` and the center of your image as at `(50, 50)` then the difference is `(50, 30)`.
- Perform a [rectangular to polar conversion](http://www.teacherschoice.com.au/maths_library/coordinates/polar_-_rectangular_conversion.htm) to get an angle value.  This will be in radians; you might want to convert it to degrees for convenience.  Store that value as `StartAngle`.
- Each time the mouse is moved, perform the two steps above again, but instead of storing the resulting angle as `StartAngle`, subtract it from StartAngle.  What you have now is `DeltaAngle`, the rotational difference between when you started spinning the image and the mouse's current position.
- Apply `DeltaAngle` to the image as a degree of rotation.

Comment: But it's not very resourceful as my mouse could be at a different point I can't be applying the same method for all points of the bitmap?

Comment: @Gwenda.T: This is assuming that you want to rotate around the center of the bitmap.  If not, you can adjust the algorithm to compensate for it.